# Elegant way for getting field defaults on a typing.NamedTuple

Tags: python

Let's say I have a `typing.NamedTuple` looking like this:

```
class Bla(typing.NamedTuple):
    a: str
    b: int = 666
    c: str = 'blah'
```

I know that I can `Bla._field_types` will give me a mapping of field names to their types, and `Bla._field_defaults` will give me a mapping of field names to their default values.

I know about the rule that anything prefixed with `_` shouldn't be used, but I know that's not always the case with named tuples. E.g. the `_asdict()` present even in the old `namedtuple` from `collections` is OK to use, it just has the underscore to avoid potential name collisions.

At the same time, there's `typing.get_type_hints`, which works similar to `_field_types` in this case:

```
>>> Bla._field_types
OrderedDict([('a', <class 'str'>), ('b', <class 'int'>), ('c', <class 'str'>)])
>>> typing.get_type_hints(Bla)
{'a': <class 'str'>, 'b': <class 'int'>, 'c': <class 'str'>}
```

but that's a more general function, that works for more things than `typing.NamedTuple`s.

So is anyone aware of any reasons NOT to use `_field_defaults`?

To give some context, I need that for a dynamic piece of code that takes different classes inheriting from `typing.NamedTuple` and instantiates them based on values in the environment.

Comment: `_field_types` is a [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NamedTuple) attribute, so I don't see a reason not to use it.

Comment: Yeah, that seems reasonable.

Answer (score 2):

`_field_types` was only available in [`typing.NamedTuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NamedTuple), it was never part of the underlying [`collections.namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) API. It is a deprecated feature and was removed in Python 3.9, so it shouldn't be used in newer code.

`_field_defaults`, on the other hand, is a [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._field_defaults) feature of NamedTuples, available in both modules. It ***is*** part of the API, not an internal feature or implementation detail, so feel free to use it.

Furthermore, it's not that *"things prefixed with `_` shouldn't be used **at all**"*. The convention is that it should not be used ***outside instances of the defining class***. So it's perfectly fine to use it in any of the class (or its sub classes) methods. So if you really want to follow the convention, you can add a "public" method that exposes `_field_defaults`:

```py
class Bla(typing.NamedTuple):
    a: str
    b: int = 666
    c: str = 'blah'

    def field_defaults(self):
        return self._field_defaults
```

Note this is just a *convention*, not a hard rule. And in the case of `NamedTuple` it doesn't even apply: `_field_defaults` only has the leading `_` for the same reason you mentioned about `_asdict()`: to prevent collisions with actual field names. The `_` here means "unobtrusive", not "private".